# In my US income tax return, is it okay to use my spouse bank account for direct deposit?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income-tax-refund

We file as "married, separately", and my name does not show in my spouse bank account. In my US income tax return, is it okay to use my spouse bank account for direct deposit? Any concerns?

Answer (score 3):

It is not OK. Unfortunately, the IRS doesn't (currently) force the banks to enforce the name matching between the account and the beneficiary. But it may trigger some mechanisms for fraud detection and protection, since that's how all the tax-refund identity thefts work.

This may (and hopefully soon will) change though as technically this shouldn't be allowed to work.